# alternative to group_by in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, ruby-on-rails-5

We have 4 models

```
channel 
has_many :channel_types

channel_type
has_many :posts
has_many :campaigns, through: :posts

post
belongs_to :channel_type
belongs_to: :campaign

campaign
has_many :posts
has_many :channel_types, through: :posts
```

we are trying to find a rails way of getting all the posts for a channel_type, BUT per campaign. we can get all the campaigns, and all the posts individually but getting the posts per campaign in a succinct way seems to be restricted to using group_by. is this the only way we can do it? or is there a way to use scoping in the model or something else?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "BUT per campaign"? Please provide an example of the data and the expected output. Also you should note that there is a huge difference between `.group` and `.group_by`. `.group` adds a `GROUP BY` clause to the SQL query. `.group_by` is from Enumerable - it will pull all the records out of the database and then iterate through them in Ruby which is a huge scaling problem.

Comment: at the moment we can get all the posts for each channel_type but this does not split them down per campaign.
i.e. a query like channel_type.posts will return all the posts that have ever occurred for this channel_type. But we are looking for a way to return the posts for the channel_type, split down per campaign.